# Часто крашется Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, nvidia

Во время работы очень часто ubuntu крашется. Думал что все из за драйвера Nvidia, но через некоторое время опять вскакивает чёрный экран. На экране все время

EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __exit4_find_entry:1531

И

systemd-journald[341]: Failed to write entry

В Linux-се новичок. Помогите пожалуйста! Не знаю что уже сделать, все форумы перелистал, это моя последняя надежда. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Жесткий диск умер.

Comment: ссд так часто делают, даже новые... работало пару часов и бац. выключил включил - опять работает. несите диск в гарантийку если есть. если нет - то покупайте новый, на дохлом диске запускаться будет, но работать серьёзно не получится

Comment: Заменил жёсткий диск, но сегодня опять упал (